# How to use a double array in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, indexing, points

I'm trying to use a double array to make a ccp. So I'm looping through my array called `grid1x` for the X axis and `grid1y` for the Y axis like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [grid1x count]; i++) 
{
    p = ccp(x*sw/768,sh-y*sh/1024);
    grab = [[Grab alloc] initWithPosition:p];
    [grabs addObject:grab];
    [batch1 addChild:grab z:5];
    [grab release];
}
```

The line

```
p = ccp(x*sw/768,sh-y*sh/1024);
```

Works perfect when I provide `x` and `y` individually, but I cannot figure out how to use them at the index position of the array. I do know to use `[grid1x objectAtIndex:i];` but cannot get it to work either.

Comment: Your question omits a lot of detail (`Grab`, `x`, `y` etc. definitions) but a guess is you have an array of `NSNumber` *objects* - you cannot put a `double` (or other primitive type) value into an Objective-C, there are included wrapped as instances of `NSNumber`. Try something like `[grid1x[i] doubleValue]` which given an `NSNumber` returns the value it wraps as a `double`.

Comment: Are you asking how to use a 2 dimensional array?  Like CRD indicated, very confused as to the actual question.  If you wanted to use x and y to index your array, simple write an indexing function that did something like:  int getIndex(int x, int y) { return y * (width) + x; }  (where width is the number of x).

Comment: @CRD forgive me, I have handled everything else but that part. Where p = ccp(... I want to replace x with the current position at grid1x and the same for y. I hope this clears things a bit better.

Comment: @KirkSpaziani I'm not sure on 2D arrays but no, I'd like to use the value at grid1x's position to replace x and grid1y's position to replace y. Would 2D arrays be a better example of doing this?

Comment: @Andrew - If I understand you want what I wrote above for `x` and for `y` you need `[grid1y[i] doubleValue]`. These expressions index the array, and then apply `doubleValue` to the result - *assuming* you've `NSNumber` objects in your two arrays.